# Lua - '<name>' expected near 'local'

Tags: lua

Делал скрипт для **SAMP** на **lua** и столкнулся с проблемой. **Скрипт не запускается** и пишет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю, что проблема в 202 строке, вот она:

```
local directIni = 'TreasureFinder.ini'
local mainini = inicfg.load(inicfg.load({
    settings = {
        klad=true,
        tres=true,
        sizetr=3,
        sizetext=12,
        cmd='tfm',
        work=true,
        defaultState=false,
        dis=true,
    },
}, directIni))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема вызвана строкой, которая расположена выше 202-ой.
Вы просто не закончили корректно предыдущий стейтмент, и Lua считает, что слово "local" - это его продолжение, а не начало нового.